# Laravel app not work after restarting virtual server using Vagrant

Tags: laravel, composer-php, vagrant

Everything is absolutely great except after restarting the virtual server

my Homestead.yaml

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

folders:
    - map: D:\www\laravel\project
      to: /home/vagrant/laravel

sites:
    - map: laravel.test
      to: /home/vagrant/laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

steps

```
VAGRANT UP
...
cd /home/vagrant/laravel
...
composer create-project laravel/laravel .
```

After navigating to laravel.test everything is working fine. But after

```
vagrant halt
vagrant up
```

i got an error

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a cached config file. I'd run through the usual suspects:
- composer update
- composer dump-autoload
- php artisan config:clear
- php artisan cache:clear

Comment: on composer update i got an error


***[RuntimeException]
  Could not scan for classes inside "/home/vagrant/laravel/vendor/sebastian/object-enumerator/src/" which does not ap pear to be a file nor a folder*** 

on dump autoload
**Generating optimized autoload filesClass Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts is not autoloadable, can not call post-autoload-dump script**
on php artisan config:clear

**PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in /home/vagrant/laravel/bootstrap/app.php:14**

Comment: Well, now that sounds even worse. Things almost seem backwards. Did you initialize your vagrant box with the homestead.yaml with that project directory already in place? VM permissions on the root-shared directory - D:\www\laravel\project will get tricky because the hoat os owns that. It's easier to share the parent dir (d:www) then you can ssh into the vm, CD to that dir, and create the project like you did before. The homestead.yaml approach of per-project mapping is better for existing projects. Either way, you'll still need the site and database entries per project though.

Comment: looks like that was helpful for me after creating the project inside VB 

composer global require laravel/homestead --dev then i just make a homestead and everything work after restarting